# Pandas Sub-String of 1 Column as Value of a New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe . In Description column, I have a fixed text.
I want to search the text for start of the position and the length. I got this all right

```
             Des          pos  end  
Call Number             
CALL2208409  <large text> 722  972
```

Then I am trying to add 4th column starting pos and ending at end. I tried this as well as the slice version.

```
df['col4']=df.col3.str[df['pos1']:df['end1']]
```

But I got NaN and col4 automatically getting float types. Setting .astype did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure pandas only supports string slicing if the start/stop is the same across all rows. You can use iteration or an `apply` func like so:

Data creation

```
large_text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis tincidunt augue. Pellentesque volutpat iaculis massa. Fusce mattis placerat malesuada. Nulla sed quam tincidunt, rhoncus risus eget, eleifend ex. Nullam interdum nulla in mattis luctus. In ac imperdiet lectus, vel rutrum mauris. Mauris pellentesque nulla ut imperdiet posuere. Vivamus porttitor placerat ante non fermentum. Vestibulum pulvinar suscipit feugiat.
""".strip()

df = pd.DataFrame({"large_text": [large_text] * 2, "start": [5, 10], "end": [20, 20]})

print(df)
                                          large_text  start  end
0  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...      5   20
1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...     10   20
```

Using `apply` to extract the substring (note that this is essentially the same as iteration)

```
df["extracted"] = df.apply(lambda s: s["large_text"][s["start"]: s["end"]], axis=1)

print(df)
                                          large_text  start  end        extracted
0  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...      5   20   ipsum dolor si
1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...     10   20       m dolor si
```

An alternative is to use a regular expression along with the `str.extract` method to extract the desired chunk instead of getting a start/end position. However, since I don't know what your data look like I'm not certain this will work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try a lambda function to iterate on all rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['hello world', 1, 5]],
    index=[0],
    columns=['description', 'start', 'end'])
df.apply(lambda x: x['description'][x['start']:x['end']], axis=1)
```

The result is as you intend:

```
0    ello
```